# VBA Populate a newly added column in a table object with vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a payroll workbook where a dynamic salary is added to a "database" sheet with all employee information and each month there is an appraisal for each employee based on a score where their salaries being calculated.

I need to add each months' final salary list to the "Employee Information" Sheet for future reference, based on the employee number.

I'm Stuck where I added a column at the end of the table yet need to populate said column with this month data.

here is my current progress.

```
Sub Finalize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Employee Information")
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Employeeinfo")
'add a new column at the end of the table
tbl.ListColumns.Add.Name = Range("Curr_Mon").Value
currcol = Range("Curr_Mon").Value

With Sheet2.ListObjects("Employeeinfo").ListColumns(currcol).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP([@[Employee Number]];'Salary Sheet'!A:G;6;FALSE)"
End With


If Err = 0 Then MsgBox "Successful", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Yet I receive a subscript out of range error, I'm here to learn and need to understand what i did wrong.

Thank you

Comment: :=VBA uses comma as separator, even if your localization involves ";", So, please try using `"=VLOOKUP([@[Employee Number]],'Salary Sheet'!A:G,6,FALSE)"`. Then, what is `[@[Employee Number]]`? Or, what will you like it to be...

Comment: Additonally you also should look at currcol.

Comment: currcol is the value of the month and the name of the column which is in this case 01/02/2022

Comment: @FaneDuru same error of subscript

Comment: What about `[@[Employee Number]]`?

Comment: @FaneDuru [@[Employee Number]] is the referenced column name of the vlookup that contains the value of the employee number in a given row such as 
Employee Number
BEG-AC-001

Comment: You cannot use **a column** as `Lookup value`. It should be a cell, which will automatically be incremented if you apply the formula on a whole column.

Comment: This formula gives the desired outcome yet needs to be filled manually with each new month, im trying to automate it with a submit button where a given column salaries will be appended to the database table where the salary corrosponds to the employee number

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm not sure i follow

Comment: So, do you have a working formula  using `[@[Employee Number]]` as  `Lookup value`?

Comment: yes it does work in the sheet yet i'm just trying to automate the process of adding the column and filling in the data

Comment: and afterwards replace #NA with 0s